# python csv is separating too much

Tags: python, csv

here's my code

```
 f= open('test1.txt','r') 
 todo = open('fb12.txt','w')     
 reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
 writer = csv.writer(todo)     
 for row in reader:
     writer.writerows(row)
```

I want the output to  be just the same as the input it should look like this

```
"DDD","3D Systems Corporation","23.47","1100203190","n/a","Technology","Computer Software: 
 etc.
```

instead I got this:

```
"""",D,D,D,"""",",","""",3,D

S,y,s,t,e,m,s

C,o,r,p,o,r,a,t,i,o,n,"""",",","""",2,3,.,4,7,"""",",","""",1,1,0

S,o,f,t,w,a,r,e,:

P,r,e,p,a,c,k,a,g,e,d
```

HELP!

Comment: is `delimeter=' '` a typo? don't you mean `delimiter=','`?

Comment: yeah... that was screwing it up... i just took away those parameters and it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got one too many layers of iteration :-)

Replace the for-loop with:

```
writer.writerows(reader)
```

Or change the *writerows* to *writerow*:

```
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: well, i'll be damned... that worked, up  voting/accepting this one fellas